# Getting notified when an encapsulating NSTableView cell is selected?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

When a stock NSTableView's row/cell is selected, its background becomes blue and any standard NSTextfields text color becomes white.

Is there a public API that lets you to get a message when an encapsulating row view or cell view is selected? Basically, I want to make a custom view that changes colors when the row/cell is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cells don't get selected, table rows do. `NSTableRowView` has a `selected` property.

I think you should just rely on your view being asked to draw (i.e. being marked as needing display) when the row changes whether or not it's selected. It can then query the properties of its enclosing row view to decide *how* it should draw.

That said, you shouldn't necessarily use the `selected` property of the row to decide how to draw. Rather, you often should use the `interiorBackgroundStyle` of the row. Or, if you're using `NSTableCellView` for your cell view, check its `backgroundStyle`. In many case, you won't have to check; the cell view will forward the setting of `backgroundStyle` to its subviews, if they support that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So you just have to add a backgroundStyle property to your custom view and check for that... Sounds pretty elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of NSTableViewDelegate . You can use 
tableViewSelectionDidChange for that. Please refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableViewSelectionDidChange: .